# org-agenda - exclude default international holidays?

Tags: org-agenda

my org-agenda setup is pretty default.

How can I make it exclude default international days?

For example,

```
Sunday 29 May 2022
Diary: Ascension of Baha'u'llah

Monday 30 May 2022
Diary: Memorial Day
```

I'm now sure where this setting is coming from and how to disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just need to set `org-agenda-include-diary` variable to `nil`.

[See this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/13236/25937) if you need more control over which holidays are displayed there.