# Birthday in org-contacts

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I am a beginner in org-mode (and Emacs, for that matter), but I thought that org-mode would be a good place/format to store my contacts. One thing I like to do is to add birthdays to contacts. I found [org-contacts.el](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/index.html), which appears to have what I want: I add a person in contacts.org and add a birthday property.

```
* Ficitive Person
:PROPERTIES:
:EMAIL: fp@example.com
:BIRTHDAY: 2000-09-24
:END:
```

Now in another file (agenda.org), I have the following:

```
* Birthday
%%(org-contacts-anniversaries)
```

When I press `C-c a a` (`M-x org-agenda-list`), I see their birthday and how old they are, cool!

However, for some people I know their birthday, but not their age. Still I'd like to see that it is their birthday on my calendar, but when I enter a birthday in any other format, I get an error:

```
Bad sexp at line 24 in [...]/org/agenda.org: (org-contacts-anniversaries)
```

Is there a format for inserting birthdays without knowing the year?

Like I said, I am an emacs noob, so if there is another better way than org-contacts (or org-mode, for that matter) I am happy to learn that way.

Comment: Does something tolerable like `0000` work in this situation as a workaround?  See also this related thread entitled **Programmatically add birthdays/holidays to agenda view in org-mode**:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10872/2287  The method described in the aforementioned link does *not* require a birth year.

Answer (score 4):

org-contacts has one format for birthdays

> BDAY:%04d-%02d-%02d,

which means 4 digits of year dash two digits of month dash two digits to day.

I can suggest to edit the format of the anniversary agenda entry. By default the format is:

> Birthday: %l (%Y),

where %l - Link to the heading and %Y - Number of year (ordinal).

So you can put random year in the contact's birthday and edit line 110 in file [org-contacts](http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob_plain;f=contrib/lisp/org-contacts.el;hb=HEAD): remove (%Y) and result will be **Birthday: Contact Name** without years.

Another way than org-contacts described in comments.